# Computing symbolic norm of a vector

Tags: vector

Consider the code:

```
n1 := Cos[α] Sin[β]
n2 := Sin[α] Sin[β]
n3 := Cos[β]
n := {n1, n2, n3}
Norm[n]
```

Why the result is

```
Sqrt[Abs[Cos[β]]^2 + Abs[Cos[α] Sin[β]]^2 + Abs[Sin[α] Sin[β]]^2]
```

that is
$$\sqrt{\left| \sin (\alpha ) \sin (\beta )\right| ^2+\left| \cos (\alpha ) \sin (\beta )\right| ^2+\left| \cos (\beta )\right| ^2}$$

instead of $1$?

How to compute the norm in a symbolic way simplifying some trigonometric identities?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
n1 := Cos[α] Sin[β]
n2 := Sin[α] Sin[β]
n3 := Cos[β]
n := {n1, n2, n3}

FullSimplify[Norm[n], {α, β} ∈ Reals]

(* 1 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

For real values, there is another way, because then you don't need the `Abs` which is created by `Norm`. It is simply

```
Simplify[Sqrt[n.n]]

(* 1 *)
```